# Convert varchar to date without timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I am trying to `convert/select` the `nvarchar` datatype to date format `(YYYY-MM-DD)`.

The table contains the date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format & also the null values.

[image]

Below SQL query is working fine but it has timestamp in the output

```
 select Date4 =  Convert(datetime, Last_Paid_Date, 103) FROM table

 2021-01-30 00:00:00.000
```

My requirement is to have only the date in `(YYYY-MM-DD)` format

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Use `CONVERT(DATE, ....)` to just convert to a date only - no time portion

Comment: @marc_s Getting error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" while performing CONVERT(DATE, ....) operation

Comment: @KarthickSambanghi please provide a [mre] of the error because marc_s's solution works [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6375944c2ac96a87ca510da7c2a63c99). Most likely you have bad data, which is what happens when you store dates as `varchar` instead of correctly as a `date`.

Comment: @KarthickSambanghi: if you have a newer version of SQL Server, you could also use `TRY_CONVERT(DATE, .....)` which will return `NULL` for those entries that are invalid dates

Answer (score 2):

normally this should work

```
select Convert(date, Last_Paid_Date, 103) from tablename
```

But if you get conversion errors you can try this

```
SELECT convert(date, convert(datetime, Last_Paid_Date, 103)) FROM TableName
```

if `Date` cannot be used to convert from your format, the trick is to convert to a datetime first, and then convert that into a date.

Much much better would be to store the data in a column with type `Date` instead of `varchar` off course

I find [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/) also some good reading

**EDIT**

if you keep getting conversion errors, then probably there are invalid dates in your varchar column. That is why you should never never never store dates/time in a varchar column.

To fix this, you could use this

```
SELECT try_Convert(date, Last_Paid_Date, 103) from tablename
```

this will put `NULL` in all columns that have an invalid date/time.

Drawback is that from all the rows that will have a value NULL, you cannot know if the original value was also NULL or an invalid date/time value.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below.

```
SELECT Date4 = CONVERT(DATE, Last_Paid_Date, 103) FROM TableName
```

OR

```
SELECT Date4 = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)  FROM TableName
```

This will remove the `Timestamp` and give you only the `Date` values in the (YYYY-MM-DD) format.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, I have tried already but getting error as "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Answer (score 0):

You can go for simple conversion.

```sql
SELECT Convert(date, '20/01/2020', 103)
```

> 2020-01-20

You can go for conversion for the table as given below:

```sql
SELECT Convert(date, val, 103) as dateval FROM 
(
values
('20/01/2020'),(null)
) as t(val)
```

| dateval |
| --- |
| 2020-01-20 |
| NULL |

Answer (score 0):

You can chain two conversions : the first one converts the original dd/mm/yyyy (103) to a datetime value, and the second conversion turns that datetime into a yyyy-mm-dd (120) string.

```
select Date4 = convert(varchar(10), convert(date, Last_Paid_Date, 103), 120) 
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your query is that the column: "Last_Paid_Date" contains NULL String, which needs the conversion as they are characters.

You can try the below query:

```
SELECT convert(date, REPLACE(Last_Paid_Date,'NULL','01/01/2001'), 103)
    , convert(datetime, REPLACE(Last_Paid_Date,'NULL','01/01/2001'), 103)   
FROM table
```

The query will replace the NULL strings with a default value if any and then do the date/datetime conversions accordingly